# How can I remove Files Tab in Teams with Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to remove or modify the `Files` tab in Teams via the Graph API:

[image]

I could remove the `Wiki` tab, but it is not possible to modify or remove the `Files` tab. I think the reason is because I can not get it with this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/XXXX-XXXX-4ef9-baa1-a3f910759d79/channels/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYe9a0bff@thread.tacv2/tabs
```

I know that DELETE endpoint is available, but not sure if it is possible to remove.

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, there is no way to do it. On the other hand, according with some conferences at ESPC 20 it is not possible at the moment. The reason for it is because Shared Documents library is used for store teams files used in the conversation tab.